# Excel: How do I solve for a Row Number, where that number is the cell that contains a particular string that is physically closest to the target cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have this formula in B22: `=IF(ISBLANK(G22),"",IF(A22="SPEED",0,(86400*(G22-(G3)))))`

But I don't want G3 to be a fixed point in the equation. I want it to be a variable. The variable it should be is: This is the cell in column G that is adjacent to its counterpart cell in column A that contains the string "SPEED" that is also physically closest to the target row (in this case, row 22).

**The the logic should be:**

- If the cell in G22 is blank,

  - If true, return null.

    If false, run the following formula:

    - - If the cell in A22 equals "SPEED",

        - If true, return 0.
        - If false, then return the following formula:

          - Multiply 86400 by the sum of G22 adjacent minus
            G[Row Number], where
            [Row Number]=The row closest to G22 where value="SPEED" from A22:$A$3)

I can currently get the rest of the formula in place, but I don't know how to write for that variable.

Comment: this is just a combination of nested `IF` blocks, if you share sample data we can help you to build the logic. What do you mean by return null. This is not a type in Excel I would say.

Comment: @DavidLeal It’s fairly common for people to refer to the empty string `””` as “null”.

Comment: What version of Excel?  If you are an O365 user I may go about this differently than a pre-2021, non-O365 version.

Comment: Can we assume nearest row can be either before or after the target row? If that's a correct assumption, how will you handle ties?

Comment: You can use XLOOKUP() or XMATCH() on the last condition. Both can lookup values upwards, to get the first match from your current row to row 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to provide the sample data, it will make easier for us to understand what you want to get.

You can use **ADDRESS** to return these
G[Row Number]; where [Row Number]=The row closest to G22 where value="SPEED" from A22:$A$3).
Into variable; and INDIRECT it to get the value.

```
ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])
```

and

```
INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])
```

The complex one is that you want to get the value of closest ROW (in this case, row 22) which have SPEED value (which is a text), you cannot use MIN() or MAX() formula to approach or manipulate it. I suggest to use MATCH function and set the [match_type] as "1" to find the largest array value.

```
MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

the formula may looks like this, use "1" on the last syntax :

```
MATCH("SPEED";$A$1:$A$20;1)
```

And, Lets see if this complete formula work on your target :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G22);"";IF(A22="SPEED";"0";(86400*(G22-(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("SPEED";$A$3:$A$22;1);7;1)))))))
```

Comment: This works! I ended up using `Match` and `Indirect` in the final equation.

The final formula I put in there was:

`=IF(ISBLANK(G22),"",IF(A22="SPEED",0,(86400*(G22-(INDIRECT("G"&(MATCH(2,INDEX(1/($A$3:A22="SPEED"),0))+2)))))))`

Since I was trying to solve for turning G3 into a variable, if we compare to the original logic:

`(INDIRECT("G"&` says to pull the value of the cell that starts with G and ends with...

`(MATCH(2,INDEX(1/($A$3:A22="SPEED"),0))+2)))))))` which returns the nearest row where "SPEED" occurs in `A3:A22`, then `+2` to correct the offset since it starts in A3vsA1.